# How to convert a Java/Scala object to a Protocol Buffers message?

Tags: scala, object, protocol-buffers, dozer

I'm trying to convert a Java/Scala object into a Protocol Buffers message.

My object is called `IDSNumber` and it has a `doubleValue` method which returns a `java.lang.Double`. I'm trying to get it to be converted automatically to a double during [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/about.html) object conversion.

I've create a [Dozer Custom Converter](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/customconverter.html) in Scala, here:

```
class IDSConverter extends DozerConverter[IDSNumber, java.lang.Double](classOf[IDSNumber], classOf[java.lang.Double]) {
    def convertTo(source: IDSNumber, destination: java.lang.Double): java.lang.Double = {
        source.doubleValue()
    }
    def convertFrom(source: java.lang.Double , destination: IDSNumber): IDSNumber = {
        new IDSNumber(source)
    }
}
```

My Protocol Buffers message looks like the following (`shortFee` and `longFee` should be converted from the `IDSNumber` type):

```
message PerformanceSettingMessage {
    optional string                  displayCurrency           = 1;
    optional PeriodMessage           performancePeriod         = 2;
    optional int64                   conversionDate            = 3;
    optional BenchmarkOptionsMessage benchmarkOptions          = 4;
    optional string                  investmentStrategyMeaning = 5;
    optional double                  shortFee                  = 6;
    optional double                  longFee                   = 7;
}
```

I try to use the converter in the following way:

```
    val longFee  = new IDSNumber(2.0)
    val shortFee = new IDSNumber(3.0)
    // newing up a real performance settings object with IDSNumbers for shortFee and longFee
    val performanceSettings = new PerformanceSettings(Currency.apply("$"), period, fj.data.Option.none(), fj.data.Option.none(), Investment_Weighted, shortFee, longFee)

    val mapper = new DozerBeanMapper() // new DozerMapper
    val idsConverter = new IDSConverter() // my IDSNumber converter
    mapper.setCustomConverters(java.util.Arrays.asList(idsConverter)) // make it use my IDSNumber converter
    val msg = mapper.map(performanceSettings, classOf[PerformanceSettingMessage]) // map my real performanceSettings object to my PerformanceSettingsMessage generated by Protocol Buffers
```

When I run the above code, `msg` has both `shortFee` and `longFee` set to `0.0`, instead of `2.0` and `3.0`. Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong? Perhaps there's a better way (better library?) to convert these objects back and forth? Thanks!